# Help! Designing a 3 push button circuit that sends emails

Tags: rpi.gpio, sendemail

First time posting here.

I'm in a bit of panic mode because I need to deliver a project this Wednesday and I'm having issues with my coding. As the title says, I'm using a circuit of three push buttons and my intention is that when they are pressed, they send a preconfigured email. I am completely new to Python so had to learn on my own, and the code that I have is a mix of the knowledge I got + code I saw on the Internet. I tested that the circuit works fine with the aid of another code I created, so I'm positive the error is in the coding. This is what I came up with

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
import smtplib
def send_mail(subject):
gmail_user = 'x'
gmail_password = 'x'
send_to = 'x'
try:
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
server.sendmail(gmail_user,send_to,subject )
server.quit()
except:
print('Error sending email')

# emails
mylist = [
"M1",
"M2",
"M3",
]
# GPIO numbers
buttons = [8,15,23]

def buttonPressed(channel):
print(mylist[channel-5], " (GPIO" + str(channel)+")");
send_mail(mylist[channel-5])

print("set inputs and event detection")
for x in buttons:
GPIO.setup(x, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(x, GPIO.FALLING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=300)

print("wait for a button to be pressed...")
while True:
sleep(0.5)
```

I'm positive my issue is with the second part, since whenever I push a button it either doesn't even recognize I did it, or says there's a problem with this line

```
print(mylist[channel-5], " (GPIO" + str(channel)+")");
```

Can anyone help? Thank you again!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indent your code properly. If you have difficulties with the additional indentation for a code block you can alternatively insert `~~~` before and after your unchanged code as separate lines. If you get an error message related to the line mentioned in the question, copy&paste the exact error message. Check if the value of `channel-5` is a valid index. How exactly do you detect that your program doesn't recognize that you pushed a button? How did you connect the buttons and maybe other components? Simplifying the program might help to find an error.

Comment: start by writing a simple code that monitors the state of a single button and prints a message when it is pressed

Comment: It looks like you are subtracting 5 from the channel, why?  your buttons are 8, 15 and 23.  Those numbers -5 are not within the bounds of your my list.   I would change that code to just print the channel number then perform a series of if channel == n:  statements to send the correct string from the my list[array].   Alternatively, make mylist a dictionary with the key of the channel number and string. and then index it by channel.

Comment: @SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS I tried doing as you  said, but if I make series of ifs it says buttonPressed is not defined. I've tried everything under the sun and it doesn't seem to want to work for me. Changed the mylist thing so now every if sends a different message. The way I tried to do it was make an if series with the button variable, but it looks like it jumps all the way to the end and doesnt allow me to press any buttons.

Comment: Post the code which you tried to use and I will see if I can see what is wrong.  If you can ensure the layout is preserved it will help.  I am guessing that it was a typo in your code which prevented it working.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.